# How to schedule a Autosys job that should run daily once and daily thrice during month end?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, jobs, autosys

Is there a way an Autosys Job should run Daily once and during last week of the month and first week of new month it should run 3 times a day?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. I would create a seperate monthly job that would use a calendar and then use the same calendate as exclude calendar on the daily job that needs to run just once.